# pareser error while sending data as json to php script using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm sending some data to my sever at `localhost` using jquery's `$.ajax`.

The data is `JSON` object.

as follows:

**javascript**

```
var jso={
    "data": {
        "Game_name": "Road Rash",
        "cheat": "xyzzyspoon!",
        "effects": [
            {
                "nitro": true
            },
            {
                "chain": false
            }
        ]
    }
};
function sendData(){
var queryString=JSON.stringify(jso);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/gamers_cheats.php",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    traditional: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: queryString,
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){
    alert("Unknown Error occured :- \n "+textStatus+"\n error");
    console.log("Unknown Error occured :- \n "+textStatus+"\n error");
    }
});
}
sendData();
```

and handling data in my `php` file as:

**gamers_cheats.php:**

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
echo"\n Count:- ".count($_POST);
// This is Just a demo file
?>
```

But the problem is `$.ajax` alerts the `error:` part with `textStatus` as parsererror. Also same is happening even if I didn't use JSON.stringify.

and if The lines:

```
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    traditional: true,
    dataType: 'json',
```

were removed then the request is sent to the sever but that isn't a valid request as it adds extra slashes (`\`) to every (`"`) in `JSON` object.

like:

```
\"data\": {
        \"Game_name\": \"Road Rash\",
        \"cheat\": \"xyzzyspoon!\",
        \"effects\": [
            {
                \"nitro\": true
            },
            {
                \"chain\": false
            }
        ]
    }
```

So that gives error while processing it on server side. Is there any way to properly send `POST` JSON data using jquery ajax and to properly handle it on server?

and one more question, can i add extra `$_POST` parameters which are not in `JSON` format to my `queryString` as `data: queryString +"&&navigator="+navigator.userAgent+""` ? but that also ain't working (This is not important though, Just curious about it).

FYI I'm running IIS 7 server with php 5.2 and JQuery version 1.7.2 with JSON2.js .

Hope experts here will help me.

Comment: Seems like a server issue to me; magic quotes?

Comment: @Ja͢ck, I dont think so, Request is initiated, But no data is recieved there.

Comment: For one, your server script doesn't return JSON and second, JSON data is not available via `$_POST`.

Comment: If the request is of type `POST` then how come `$_POST` is empty? can you tell that.

Comment: Because: PHP .. the data can be found using `json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'))`

Comment: I'll try that, and will inform you. Thanks for quick look though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62910/discussion-between-vedant-terkar-and-jack).

Answer (score 0):

Removing the line 'var queryString=JSON.stringify(jso);' and passing object jso as data may help. Try once.